# CUDA: Memory allocation for pointer to pointer using cudaMallocHost(...);

Tags: cuda, malloc, pointer-to-pointer

I changed my method to allocate host memory from method 1 to method 2 as shown in my code below. The code can compile and run without any error.
I just wonder is it a proper way or any side effect to allocate memory for pointer to pointer using method 2.

```
#define TESTSIZE  10
#define DIGITSIZE 5

//Method 1  
int **ra;
ra = (int**)malloc(TESTSIZE * sizeof(int));
for(int i = 0; i < TESTSIZE; i++){
    ra[i] = (int *)malloc(DIGITSIZE * sizeof(int));
}

//Method 2  
int **ra;
cudaMallocHost((void**)&ra, TESTSIZE * sizeof(int));

for(int i = 0; i < TESTSIZE; i++){
    cudaMallocHost((void**)&ra[i], DIGITSIZE * sizeof(int));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of them work fine. Yet, there are differences between `cudaMallocHost` and `malloc`. The reasons is that `cudaMallocHost` allocates pinned memory so under the hood the OS's doing something similar to `malloc` and some extra functions to pin the pages. This means that `cudaMallocHost` generally takes longer.

That being said, if you repeatedly want to `cudaMemcpy` from a single buffer then `cudaMallocHost` may benefit in the long run since it's quicker to transfer data from pinned memory.

Also, you are **required** to use pinned memory to overlap data transfer/computations with `streams`.